# How do the Unicode control characters work?

Tags: android, unicode

What I'm doing now is to show the phone number correctly under right-to-left layout. I want **+111111111** but it appears like **111111111+** now. I found a solution that using LRM(left-to-right mark), which is a Unicode control character **'\u200E'**.

There may be several formats for phone numbers in different place of world like XXX-XXX-XXXX. To prevent further bugs, I have to understand how those control characters work, especially which changes the direction of strings.

In my understanding, for common characters:

1. strings are stored as bytes in memory.
2. the editor/textview loads the bytes and look them up in
   Unicode.
3. the editor/textview shows those Unicode in the form of
       fonts.

So, when or which step do those control characters like LRM work? How to make sure that using them does not cause further bugs?

I wish I had made it clear for you.

Comment: Why you can't just use RTL support in Android? http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

Comment: The interpretation of these characters *generally* follows the Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm: http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/

Comment: @Divers Actually I do using RTL support. I just cannot get a right phone number with a plus in front of it. I have to force LTR for the phone number or the plus will appear at the end.